Issues with noisy fingerprint images using libfprint on Ubuntu 22.04 and Raspberry Pi OS
I'm experiencing an issue when trying to use libfprint to capture fingerprint images on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and Raspberry Pi OS. I have followed the steps outlined in the official documentation, but when I run ./libfprint/build/demo/gtk-libfprint-test to test fingerprint acquisition, the captured image appears noisy and lacks the distinctive shape of a fingerprint.
Here is a screenshot of the result I am getting:

My Device (DigitalPersona 4500):

What I've Tried:

I’ve followed all the steps in the libfprint documentation for installation and setup.
Since the fingerprint device functions well on Windows, I don’t think it’s a hardware issue.
I’ve tested this on two Linux-based operating systems: Ubuntu 22.04 and Raspberry Pi OS, but I’m seeing the same problem on both.

Has anyone else experienced noisy or unclear fingerprint captures with libfprint? Could this be a configuration issue on Linux or something specific to libfprint? Any advice on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated.

The project seems still to be maintained, and apparently there is an IRC channel for it.  That might be a more fruitful place to seek support.

I have the same exact problem, I'm looking for a solution too

@Macarthurval I would like to know if you ever managed to solve it, I've been dealing with this for days

Does /var/log/syslog say anything?

@WalterChapilliquen-wZVanG Nope, finally I'm doing my implementation with the UareU SDK

@WalterChapilliquen-wZVanG Could you verify the permissions of usb device using lsusb and also try configuring the udev rules for the hardware device
